CURRENT_TIME default value in MySQL
Newbie here.
I am following Dani Krossing's course over php on YouTube. So far it has been excellent, but I cannot get past this section on MySQL databases (time stamped): https://youtu.be/KMYZqb88Wm0?si=MmX3uTlbs0X9GjGi&t=1678
It keeps returning a 1064 error despite my code being word-for-word. Help would be greatly appreciated so that I can continue on to the next step!
Code Compared with Error Message
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    pwd VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_TIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)' at line 6

I was trying to follow along with Krossing's video and was expecting it to work but got this error instead.

I am guessing Dani is using MariaDB and not MySQL. See MySQL and MariaDB

'The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/datetime.html , 'MariaDB displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ffffff' format, but allows assignment of values to DATETIME columns using either strings or numbers. For details, see date and time literals.
DATETIME columns also accept CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default value.' - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/datetime/

mysql and mariadb are not interchangeable you should check what the tutorial is using and what you have installed.

@P.Salmon I checked the tutorial and it claims to use mysql. If I go back one earlier episode in the series of tutorials, then the author refers to xampp, which uses mariadb, not mysql. Unfortunately, xampp keeps referring to the database as mysql on its control panel and the author does not seem to understand the distinction either.

@Shadow - It seems you are suggesting Dani is confused and not using SQL due to the use of XAMPP. Is that correct? If so, I suppose I'll just find a better tutorial.

If you are otherwise happy with the tutorial and are aware of potential issues sticking with it and adapting as required will be good practice,,The problem I have with tutorials is that they don't always march in time with version changes to the software and I have to adapt,

@P.Salmon the tutorial has culminated in this so far and builds off of it, so without it working in MySQL phpMyAdmin or XAMPP I cannot move forward, and it seems to work on neither. I'm super fresh to this, so I'm not able to innovate quite yet.

@WillS. a lot of people make the assumption that MySQL is the same as MariaDB. In reality they should be treated as different products even if they have a lot of similarities.

@ErgestBasha Thanks for the heads up. Would you suggest finding another tutorial or is there some way for me to make this work in XAMPP or phpMyAdmin so that I can move forward?

@Rairot's solution seems to have worked. Thanks for the help y'all.

Why if the tutorial uses XAMPP have you installed mysql? Perhaps step back and bring your environment into line with the tutorial

@WillS. I suggest you adapt use created_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and you are good to go.  See example.  IMO it is better facing such issues , you learn a lot . As per tutorial I could not say, I prefer books.

@WillS. yes, the author of the tutorial made a mistake. A very common one. Just today this is the 3rd question I encounter that refers to mysql in conjunction with xampp. However, if you follow a certain tutorial, then you should match its environment exactly, i.e. you should be using xampp as well.

Another option might be to try WAMPServer instead, then you get MySQL and mariaDB both installed and you can use either or both

@shadow I'm disappointed to hear how relative SQL is to the environment. I am trying to learn php to get away from the relativity of web development through Wordpress. Is there a more direct way to do databases that is more absolute or objective and is not contingent on the environment? Does this ultimately come down to php and SQL manipulating C code indirectly? I'd like to learn the most direct way possible with the fewest contingencies, subjectivity, relativity, etc. possible.

@Shadow I was using XAMPP originally, as in the video, and switched to my cpanel only after I thought my text editor (Notepad++) might be the culprit (it wasn't), in order to try it out. XAMPP has the same phpMyAdmin panel as cpanel.

Phpmyadmin is just a GUI tool, it is not relevant in this case. You may have had xampp installed, but you used a mysql instance and not a mariadb one. Your error message says mysql, while a mariadb one will say mariadb.

@Shadow Thank you for your patience. Does MariaDB use the SQL area within phpMyAdmin and the MySQL module on XAMPP? He was using these on the tutorial and I was following along exactly. All of his settings he had me go through and that he is using himself are SQL, so I guess what I am having cognitive dissonance about is how he has the same settings as me but gets different results from the same code (which is MariaDB?). XAMPP didn't return any errors, it simply didn't work when I used my form. I was able to move forward on cpanel, but the next step is also returning an error on cpanel.

@WillS. Keep in mind that you always will depend from the DBMS used. SQL is a language that might be differently implemented on different  DBMS such as MySQL, MariaDB , SQL Server etc. For example group_concat MySQL function does not exists on SQL Server, but you can use string_agg. Basically I am saying there is no "Just SQL"

@Ergest Basha Thank you for letting me know. Both my cpanel and XAMPP say they are using MySQL. Should I expect that they are still going to be different? Do I have to design a new database every time I transition between a program, even if they are both using MySQL? And sorry to ask another question, but why might he be getting good results using the same programs and settings and the same-- apparently wrong-- language? Is this to be expected? I'm having a difficult time getting an idea where to begin learning if I can't learn the language and apply it as needed. A little disheartening.

You probably had mysql installed and you configured your clients to work with mysql as opposed to xampp's mariadb.

@Shadow AI is saying that MariaDB is default in XAMPP, and I haven't made any configuration changes.

You probably had mysql installed separately and pointed your clients to it. Sorry, there is no other explanation.

@Shadow I didn't take any extra steps, so I guess I'll wait to see if someone else chimes in. Thanks for your help so far.

Mysql does not install and configure itself. Considering you had no idea that mysql and mariadb were two different products a couple hours ago, there is a high chance you simply missed something. But nobody was there when you installed and configured your environment so I guess we will never know for sure.

@Shadow MySQL came with XAMPP. I didn't download it independently. I followed the tutorial: youtu.be/GRqw0pBwewY?si=IMOACAhiInlzFzjp . MySQl is also a part of cpanel, which has also been tried. I'm not trying to have an argument.

@Everyone Could I be having path issues with Notepad ++? He had to set the path on his editor, but he was using Visual and it seemed like an issue specific to that. This wouldn't explain the problems on cpanel, though. AI is telling me the code between cpanel and XAMPP phpMyAdmin should be interconvertible and that there should be no issues, including with MariaDB. I'm stuck hard on this one.

Mysql ihasnot been part of xampp for several years, so it could not have come with that. Cpanel is a web histing management software. I'm sorry, but you do not seem to know what you installed via what. And no, this issue has nothing to do with notepad++. Notepad++ is just as advanced text editor.

@Shadow The module I am running on XAMPP is called MySQL. It's also what Dani was using on the tutorial, and he never suggested downloading MySQL separately from XAMPP. Cpanel has the same SQL section as XAMPP. If you're saying I need to update something on the backend, that is different from my access to SQL not having come with my XAMPP and cpanel, because that's how I got access to SQL: it came with these. If MySQl was exchanged for MariaDB then that does not cohere with your original claim that the problem is that I am using MariaDB confused for SQL.

I never claimed that you use mariadb. The author of the tutorial uses mariadb. You use mysql. If you installed mysql through cpanel, then you may have both mysql and mariadb installed. As I wrote in my first comment addressed to P.Salmon, xampp unfortunately still refers to mariadb as mysql on its control panel. This does confuse a lot of people - not a big surprise.

@Shadow my cpanel is on an external server outside of possession, whereas XAMPP is being used locally and in my possession, so an install of SQL should not affect XAMPP. This being so, if Dani is using MariaDB from XAMPP in his tutorial from a year ago, then even if there was a shift, I too should have MariaDB after following his tutorial, since you suggest that this shift occurred years prior. So the discrepancy still remains unsolved.

Then I do not know ehy you brought up cpanel in the first place. Well, good luck figuring out how mysql got installed on your computer. Or, you can focus on living with mysql. Or you can focus on removing mysql and bring mariadb forward. Your call.

@Shadow I brought cpanel up because I tested the code Dani was using on cpanel after it was failing to work with form data in XAMPP. On XAMPP it did not show errors, but failed to process the data. On cpanel, errors were given. What I would like to do is just learn whatever it is that cpanel is operating on so that I can use php on my webpage. Everything I had read, including from AI, had said that SQL coding between XAMPP and cpanel would be inter-convertible.

Since I cannot even seem to get started with SQL I have decided to switch direction and move toward DOM instead. I was super excited to learn php and SQL together, but there seems to be something happening beyond my control on this one. DOM seems to be more under my control so far.

CURRENT_TIME does not return a DATETIME
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime
What you are probably after is TIMESTAMP instead, something like this:
created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Thank you @Rairot. Someone had commented that this would not work, but after trying it it did.
